# How to get App Files Dir to a Class?

Tags: android, android-context

I made a new class to handle FTP downloads and store them in /files/ folder within my App.

I've hardcoded the directory path but I want to use a more efficient way.

My code is:

```
public class myFTP  {

    public FTPClient connect(String ip, String user, String pass) {
         SOME CODE
     }

     public boolean download (FTPClient client, File file, String dir){
          SOME CODE
          file = new File("/data/data/com.myapp/files/"+NAME OF DOWNLOAD FILE); //Here is my problem
     }
```

I want to change "/data/data/com.myapp/files to something like context.getFilesDir() or some other function that returns this directory. How can I code that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this http://itekblog.com/android-context-in-non-activity-class/

Modified my class to this:

```
public class myFTP extends ContextWrapper {

    public myFTP(Context base) {
         super(base);
    }

    public FTPClient connect(String ip, String user, String pass) {
         SOME CODE
     }

     public boolean download (FTPClient client, File file, String dir){
          SOME CODE
          file = new File(context.getFileDir()+NAME OF DOWNLOAD FILE); //Here is my problem
     }
```

Now to call it from a service, Activity or anthing that HAS a context:

```
myFTP myftp = new myFTP(this);
```

Comment: you probably dont want a hardcoded string for the dir.  use context.getFileDir() as the "/data/data/" directory isnt whats used for all devices.  It will crash on some.

Comment: Actually I had that on my code. I changed it when I simplified the code to put here... Thanks, I've now corrected that

Answer (score 1):

You've got most of it already

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + nameOfDownloadFile);
```

This will give you a reference to the a file object in the "files" directory of your app.

Comment: I get a context Variable might not have been inicialiced. But if I try to do Contexto context = XX y can't get anything to work

Comment: getting a Context instance depends on where you are in the code.  If you are in an Activity, the Activity is used as a context object.  If not, you need to pass it into a constructor of whatever class you are using.

Comment: Solved it, I will post a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
String LocalDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

`LocalDirectory` contains the path to the external storage.